# hardhat verify ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error

Tags: hardhat, etherscan

I'm using hardhat to auto verify my contract,
However, in `await verify(simpleStorage.address, [])`, an error was reported:

> Connect TimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error

```js
const { ethers, run, network } = require("hardhat")
require("dotenv").config()

async function main() {
  const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")
  console.log("Deploying contract...")
  const simpleStorage = await contractFactory.deploy()
  await simpleStorage.deployed()
  console.log("Contract deployed to:", simpleStorage.address)
  console.log(network.config)
  if (network.config.chainId === 11155111 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6)
    await verify(simpleStorage.address, [])
  }
  const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson("ws", 751)
  await transactionResponse.wait(1)
  const favoriteNumber = await simpleStorage.retrieve("ws")
  console.log(`Current value is: ${favoriteNumber}`)
}

async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
  console.log("Verifying contract...")
  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      constructorArgsParams: args,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already Verified!")
    } else {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

here is my command and result:
[image]

here is my hardhat.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.7",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
}
```

and my package version is:

```json
{
  "name": "hardhat-simple",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "2.0.4",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.8",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "2.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ethers": "5.5.3",
    "hardhat": "2.8.3",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I solved this problem by referring to [here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/2247#discussioncomment-5496669)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It is better to include the main ideas in the answer an only use the link to expand the details.